# Get column description via smartsheet api

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

In Smartsheet interface you can add a description for each column (then the description is visible via a little popover), is there a way to retrieve it via the API ?

I cant find it in the [doc](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops! Yes, the column description can be retrieved using the API. You're also correct that it is not mentioned in our documentation. Sorry about that! Thanks for bringing it to our attention. We'll get it into the next release of the API docs.
The column object contains a 'description' property that matches the column description in the sheet. Here's an example response from a [GET column](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-column) request:

```
{
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "pageSize": 100,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalCount": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1620508178442116,
            "version": 0,
            "index": 0,
            "title": "Primary Column",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "primary": true,
            "validation": false,
            "width": 150
        },
        {
            "id": 6124107805812612,
            "version": 0,
            "index": 1,
            "title": "Column2",
            "description": "I'm a description in a column.",
            "type": "TEXT_NUMBER",
            "validation": false,
            "width": 150
        }
    ]
}
```